# javascript html popup window

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am fairly a beginner with javascript. What I want to do is when I click on a button:
[image]

I want it to popup a window. The content of this window is HTML (actually it's a .php) code. As follows:
[image]

Then when you click next it scrolls to the next list of movies. What is the easiest javascript/jQuery library to do this?

This snippet of pitcure is taken from the website getglue. I tried to firebug the site, but can't seem to find the js code to do it.

**IMPORTANT:**
The movie title and image is taken from a database, and therefore content is not static html. This is where I actually got confused on how to do a dynamic content generated window popup box

Comment: When you say "popup a window", do you mean a new browser window? Or do you mean a [lightbox effect](http://blogfreakz.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/SexyLightbox.jpg)?

Comment: something like a lightbox effect, the problem is that those movies are pulled from a database and therefore php code is needed... will lightbox effect work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a fabulous tutorial on popups with jQuery (the only way to code js)

http://yensdesign.com/2008/09/how-to-create-a-stunning-and-smooth-popup-using-jquery/

A tutorial for AJAX

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/

Comment: yes, the content of that window is static HTML.. I want a dynamic one as the movie title is pulled from the database

Comment: oh right, I forgot you were a beginner. I'm sorry. You use AJAX. I added a link to help with learning AJAX

Answer (score 3):

jQuery UI's one of the most popular tools for things like this.  They [have a dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) that you can use to achieve this affect.

Answer (score 0):

Give the button an id with the `id` attribute, then use this JavaScript code somewhere after the button's place in HTML:

```
document.getElementById('the_button_id').addEventListener('click', function() {
    window.open('page_to_open', '');
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like what Matt Ball says on using lightbox / fancybox (to pop up your form).
After that if u want the next button to slide to next list, 1st make sure the list of movies portion inside a div with id then use jqueryui event like this:

```
$("#idofyourcurrentlist").hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
$("#idofyournextlist").delay(1000).show("slide",{direction: "right"}, 1000);
```

Good Luck.

As requested:

```
var getdata = "something that  u need";
var datatopost = "yourneed=" + getdata;
$.post("tophphandling.php",datatopost,function(success){
    if(success){
       alert("Thank you.");
    }
});
```

Comment: so in my next button, what js should I put?

Comment: I can't imagine what's your build maybe your query will select all listed movies ? If it is then limit them for example the 1st page list is 0-10 and 2nd is 11-20 and so on(Calling them using $.post() ) <<==== Ajax Method in Jquery.

Comment: mind doing me a code snippet using that $.post? and yes...I limit it from 0-10 etc

Answer (score 0):

Pure **HTML** popup, using the `details` element.

It should appear centred, and dim the whole page using a large `outline`.

```css
.popup > p {
    padding: 1rem;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 25vw
}
.popup summary {
    padding: 1rem 0.5rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    max-height: 90vh;
    overflow: auto
}
.popup[open] summary {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 0.5rem;
}

.popup[open] {
    position: fixed;
    /* top: calc(50% - 25vw); */
    left: calc(50% - 15vw);
    outline: 5000px #00000090 solid;
    border: 5px red solid;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    z-index: 1;
    max-height: 90vh;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden
}

.popup[open] summary::after {
    content: '❌';
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<details class="popup">
  <summary>HTML popup</summary>
    <p>
      <span>Name</span>
      <input value="HTML"/>
      <br>
      <span>Difficulty</span>
      <input type="number" value="3"/>
      <br>
      <span>Coolness</span>
      <input type="number" min="0" max=8 step="1" value="97" />
      <br>
      <p><span>Powered by HTML</span></p>
    </p>
</details>
```

Powered by **HTML**.